# Menu not aligning with an image/link (CSS issue)

Tags: css

I am building http://www.inboundio.com and though on my localhost and server, the site looks fine, I took certain screenshots with browsershots and criticue and they showed this as website screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOJRa.png (notice at top, about us being part of the image)

I am not sure why this is happening, the page is responsive and on my localhost and server, everything looks fine. Any idea how to fix this since there is certainly some css problem which I am able to see.

**Menu Code**

```
<div class="top-menu pull-right  home-menu" id="main-menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <!-- li><a href="#features">Features</a></li -->
    <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="/plans">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/demo">Demo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body.frontend .header .top-menu {
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 140px;
}

.nav {
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
list-style: none;
}

.pull-right {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: this is because you have used it in another tag i mean it's out of ul of your navigations put it inside of `ul li` and create a fiddle of navigation links and when you put inside of top `ul li` it will easy to maintain it on all screen sizes

Comment: Please post realevant code. And better still provide an example of whiat is wrong on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @JonP - my mistake, I have edited the post and have added the relevant code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this am debug it and i found this issue

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/8dXx4/)

**use this code instead of your**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="/plans">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/demo">Demo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn btn-success pull-right login-btn" href="/users/sign_in">Sign-in</a></li>
</ul>
```

**and add this css to your style and it will work fine**

```
.frontend .nav li a.btn{margin-top:0!important;}
.frontend .nav li{line-height: 30px!important;}
```

Comment: Thanks @TP, I am fixing the code, unfortunately I can't give you vote up, I will do it once I get required 15 points

Comment: @PushkarGaikwad don't worry :-) it's a pleasure to be help someone

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some padding on the right your div if you don't want to move the sign in button to the list. USe the width of the button, plus a bit extra.

```
body.frontend .header .top-menu {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, will do it and update the post with working code.